# Manually start Arquillian Cube container created with ContainerBuilder

Tags: jboss-arquillian

Is it possible to create `Container` with `ContainerBuilder` inside test and start it manually?

Current declarative approach with `@DockerContainer` is a bit limiting.

Comment: Something like this? http://arquillian.org/arquillian-cube/#_junit_rule

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: @lordofthejars I need to create and start/stop container inside test method so Rule approach won't work for me, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then you can use another approach, look this test: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube/blob/master/docker/ftest-standalone/src/test/java/org/arquillian/cube/StandaloneITCase.java

Comment: This example does not define container using ContainerBuilder.